# SQL Server stored procedure evaluating JSON_VALUE out of execution order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In the below procedure, I am trying to return a value based on an input that is in JSON format. To protect against an invalid JSON input, I am using the ISJSON() function. However, SQL Server appears to be evaluating JSON_VALUE() in the 2nd statement prior to the ISJSON() validation check in the 1st statement.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(
    ColKey integer NOT NULL,
    ColText nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ColKey] ASC));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(ColKey, ColText)
VALUES (1, 'Test String');
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTextFromJSON]
    @JSON nvarchar(255),
    @TextOut nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN       
    IF ISJSON(@JSON) <> 1
        THROW 50000, 'Invalid JSON', 1; -- Alternatively: RETURN -1;

    SELECT TOP 1 @TextOut = ColText
    FROM dbo.Table1
    WHERE ColKey = JSON_VALUE(@JSON, N'$.Col1Key')

    RETURN 0;   
END;
GO
```

Executing the procedure with an invalid JSON string does not trigger the expected exception.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TextOut nvarchar(255);

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetTextFromJSON]
        @JSON = N'{Col1Key:1}', -- Invalid JSON: ISJSON(N'{Col1Key:1}') = 0 
        @TextOut = @TextOut OUTPUT;

SELECT @TextOut;
```

returns:

```
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.usp_GetTextFromJSON, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 29]
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'C' is found at position 1.
```

Changing the execution code to the following returns successfully.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TextOut nvarchar(255);

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_GetTextFromJSON]
        @JSON = N'{"Col1Key":1}', -- Valid JSON
        @TextOut = @TextOut OUTPUT;

SELECT @TextOut;
```

Why is SQL Server evaluating JSON_VALUE() in the 2nd statement before evaluating ISJSON in the 1st statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It''s a compilation issue not an execution issue. When you run the good one first the plan is generated and cached and the bad one then works as you want.

Probably it tries to evaluate `JSON_VALUE(@JSON, N'$.Col1Key')` against the initial parameter value so it can then use the histogram on `ColKey` to get row estimates.

You can try assigning the parameter to a local variable to avoid this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTextFromJSON] @JSON    NVARCHAR(255),
                                             @TextOut NVARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @vJSON NVARCHAR(255) = @JSON;

      IF ISJSON(@vJSON) <> 1
        THROW 50000, 'Invalid JSON', 1; -- Alternatively: RETURN -1;

      SELECT TOP 1 @TextOut = ColText
      FROM   dbo.Table1
      WHERE  ColKey = JSON_VALUE(@vJSON, N'$.Col1Key')

      RETURN 0;
  END;
```

Comment: Alternatively or additionally, if there is an actual case for using the row estimates on `ColKey` because they'll lead to different plans, the statement can be marked with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ...)`. (Marking the entire stored procedure `WITH RECOMPILE` will not help in this case, as that would still fail the compilation at a "bad" value.)

Comment: Wow, unimaginable to me that they would short-circuit an entire IF out of the execution plan based on whatever data happened to occur at the first run. Is that really how T-SQL works? Would someone know of a reference or doc for this behaviour?

Comment: sql is good its the Json that carrys bad data. Not much for json; but its the flavor or year. Lets see how long it lasts.

Comment: @PeterB: that's not what's happening. The difference is that if the procedure is first called with valid data, compilation of the batch succeeds. The `IF` is still executed if you call it again with invalid data, and the sproc will throw -- just as intended. If you first call the procedure with invalid data, compiling the second statement fails because the optimizer proactively decomposes the JSON -- the `IF` never executes in the first place in this case. It's not short-circuiting so much as evaluating the `JSON_VALUE` much earlier than expected (at compile time).

Comment: Using the local variable appears to make it tolerate invalid JSON on the first run. I would like to be able to deploy a new instance of the database without having to "initialize" the stored procedures with dummy data and I can't guarantee that the first call received from the (non-SQL Server) calling systems will be valid JSON.

Comment: @Joat: in fact, attempting to rigidly control recompilation of a stored procedure is a losing prospect (it can happen at any time due to statistics changes or memory pressure) so putting in an "initial good plan" is not a stable approach (and my comment was not meant to imply such, just in case). Making the procedure work in all circumstances is obviously the better idea.

Comment: I am assuming that this concept has broader applications than just 'JSON_VALUE'. Is any TSQL function that references input parameters at risk of skipping validation code on initial compile?

Comment: @Joat: Sounds like good material for a new question! I can't think of any off the top of my head. Arguably, even `JSON_VALUE` doing this is actually a bug (or rather, the optimizer not catching the failure is) -- if the initial value does not parse, what it logically *should* do is proceed with an unknown value for the estimation.

Comment: @Joat - It isn't a matter of skipping validation code. When the stored proc is compiled all statements in it are compiled regardless of where they are in the control flow. Generally this sort of error is suppressed though. `SELECT *
FROM sys.objects o1
WHERE name = LOG(-1)` or `SELECT *
FROM sys.objects o1
WHERE name =1/0` both generate execution plans